# Statistics of IMAP vs POP vs Exchange?

Tags: statistics, exchange-server, imap, pop3, mapi

I'm desperately looking for some statistics about usage of POP versus IMAP versus Exchange-MAPI, especially in professional context.
I know IMAP is used for accessing mails from mobile devices with limited bandwidth, whereas POP is the good old standard, and Exchange is more business-oriented.
Does someone know the approximate percentage of usage of each protocol ?

Thanks !

Comment: It sounds as if you may be trying to make an argument for support of particular protocols on a server or client. Do be aware that although POP is ubiquitous, mailboxes in the IMAP age **should** consider POP deprecated as it is dreadfully inadequate. However, like SMTP, POP will probably be around for too long.

Answer (score 2):

IMAP & POP are universal.

Exchange is for servers running exchange only. Which means you will need to purchase an exchange server, and use Outlook in order to read your email.

IMAP keeps all your email on the server (so if you read it on your mobile, then your computer will still show the message as being read)

POP will download all your mail to your computer, and delete it from the server after a time period that you can set (so you can check your email from a multiple computers within that period)

As far as actual usage statistics, I am not sure, but I highly prefer IMAP, as it lets me check my email from all 5 of my computers

Answer (score 1):

Most of the users don't use Exchange-MAPI

IMAP don't download data and keeps it on server.

POP download data and keeps it on the local system.
Due to this IMAP is fast and most of users prefer IMAP for use than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone is using Exchange-MAPI on the internet, just inside local and private networks. MAPI uses dynamic RPC calls and it is not really designed to work over the internet. I think you can use "MAPI over HTTP", but that's just a hack to enable low-end mobile devices use a local app instead of the OWA...

As of statistics, you could on the one hand search for numbers of Exchange licenses sold plus Windows CE powered smartphones and make an estimation, and on the other hand search for protocol traffic statistics for IMAP4 and POP3

Comment: RPC over HTTP isn't a hack for mobile devices.  It's a very common way for users to access hosted Exchange environment and as an alternative for full, remote Outlook access without requiring a VPN.

Comment: I agree with you, and I didn't mean that RPC over HTTP is JUST a hack for mobile devices... I meant that in my experience this is how I have seen people using it.

Answer (score 0):

hotmail on outlook using outlook connector uses mapi over http so if you think that is just "some hack" there is nothing to discuss.

I think Google licenses MAPI for some of it's calendaring and messaging.  So it's not just "some hack" for using over the internet.  Far from it.

MAPI is a full 2 way collaboration system entailing not just email but calendars, tasks, contacts etc.

IMAP is just for email.  If you just want email then IMAP is probably the way to go as it's open and the most widely used.  Unless you use Exchange.  IMAP (probably intentionally) runs like crap on Exchange compared to MAPI.  But strangely it runs fine on everything else.